Making Material segmented buttons align without cutting off text
I'm trying to do a seemingly simple usage of Material3's SingleChoiceSegmentedButtonRow, but I'm struggling to get the buttons to align with each other while not cutting off their text. Here's a minimal example:
SingleChoiceSegmentedButtonRow(
) {
    val options = listOf("Short", "Two Words", "Longer Words")
    options.forEachIndexed { index, option ->
        SegmentedButton(
            shape = SegmentedButtonDefaults.itemShape(index = index, count = options.size),
            selected = false,
            onClick = {},
            icon = {},
        ) {
            Text(
                text = option,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
            )
        }
    }
}

But the third button is taller than the others:

Based on a question with a similar problem, I added Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min) to the SingleChoiceSegmentedButtonRow and Modifier.fillMaxHeight() to the SegmentedButton. That aligned the buttons, but then cut off the text:

I've tried many combinations of fillMaxHeight, IntrinsicSize.Min, and IntrinsicSize.Max across the SingleChoiceSegmentedButtonRow, SegmentedButton, and Text, but nothing I've tried results in other outcomes.
Adding Modifier.height(40.dp) to the Text does help:

But my understanding is that hardcoded heights like that will cause trouble across different devices and font sizes.
And very cryptically, applying Modifier.padding(horizontal = 5.dp) (yes, horizontal, not vertical) to the Text works best of all:

It seems like this should be very straightforward and should not require hardcoding sizes. What am I missing?
